# Android - Dynamic buttons off the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm having a problem with some dynamically generated buttons. If given too much text, they go off the screen. You can see it in the picture:

[image]

If the text in the buttons is small then the issue doesn't show up, but if the character number is high then the button appears out of the screen.

The layout of the button is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/newGuessButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</Button>
```

And the buttons are created in a table layout:

```
   <TableLayout android:id="@+id/buttonTableLayout" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1" android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
  <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow0" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="horizontal"></TableRow>
  <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"></TableRow>
  <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"></TableRow>
```

It's important to note that this table goes inside a linear layout.

Is there anyway I can limit the size of the buttons to the size of the screen that's using them?

Comment: Do you have to use a table for this? how about a gridview?

Comment: I don't have to use a table. Is it better to use a gridview? How will it help on solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using a GridView instead of a tablelayout:

Using a GridView will be much better because:

- You can set the number of columns
- The width of all the columns will be the same
- If the text cannot fit in the textview then it will go to the next line instead of outside the
   view.

Here is some more information on using GridViews - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Great, I will try it with a gridView.